# How to use pstool in pdfLatex?

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, psfrag, epstool

Update: After I adding those `--shell -escape` commands, when I run the code as below, it still cannot work.

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{memoir}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pstool}
\input macros.tex
\EndPreamble
\begin{document}

External macros: \a, \b, \c

\pstool{trial}{%
}

\psfragfig{subdir/trial2}{%
\psfrag{[Mp]}{$Z_\b$}%
}

\end{document}
```

---

Update: The question (described in the quotation as below) is solved by deleting the space between the name of my tex file.

### But, I am still not clear of how to use the command of `pstool` combined with `psfrag`. Can anyone shed a light on this for me?

> I tried to add the package at the very beginning of the document. But,
>   there are some errors happened and the console said that 
>   `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty:93:
>   Pack age catchfile Error: File`"my files".w18' not found.`
>
> When I removed the sentence of `\usepackage{pstool}`, the compiling
>   runs well.
>
> Any suggestions will be great appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. And which distribution on what OS are you using?

Comment: Hi, @MartinSchröder! Thanks for your warmly reply. Unfortunately, I didn't know the basic usage of the `\pstool`command. So, what I am asking is a simple example that use this command with the `psfrag` command. I tried to google it. But I didn't get a simple but useful one.

Comment: As far as I understand it, your current question is requesting an example of using psfrag and pstool with pdflatex.  If so, can you edit the question so that it focuses on that question (and not the solved issue of a space in the filename)?

Comment: why do you need psfrag? You can have the right font already in your image.

Comment: Hi, @MatthewLeingang. Many thx for your detailed reply. I tried the short example as your given. But I failed to generate a pdf output. The error information is as below. `./pstest.tex:10: Package pstool Error: No graphic "gandl.eps.eps" or "gandl.eps
-psfrag.eps" found.` Here, the `gandl.eps` is the name of my eps file.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  You should [start a new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this issue.  Include the complete code for the document you are trying to compile, as well as this error message.  This is a Q&A site, not a forum; each page is for answering one and only one question.

Comment: Related: The issue with space in file name is [minted - Catchfile error when using --shell-escape flag in LaTex system preferences - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514830/catchfile-error-when-using-shell-escape-flag-in-latex-system-preferences) .

Answer (score 6):

Here is a short example of `psfrag` and `pstool` in action. I took this from the [package's example directory on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pstool/example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pstool}
\def\a{A}
\EndPreamble
\begin{document}

\psfragfig*[mode=nonstop]{trial}{%
  \color{red}
  \tiny
  \psfrag{[Mp]}{$M_\a$!}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

(The red mark is what's added with `\psfrag`.)

As egreg notes below, the `-shell-escape` option must be specified to `pdflatex` at run time.

Comment: To be run with the `-shell-escape` option.

Comment: Hi, @egreg and @MatthewLeingang , I am using the TexShop v3.11, in which the `-shell-escape` option was removed. I don't know if this is the reason that why I cannot run this simple example in my TexShop.

Comment: @datcn That's quite probable.

Comment: @datcn: Go to TexShop Preferences and look at the Engine tab.  Add `--shell-escape` to the lines with `pdftex` and `pdflatex`.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang After I adding those commands, when I run the code as above, it still cannot work.

Comment: Hm, I confess I'm confused.  I have the same version of TeXShop as you and it works for me.