# Catchfile error when using --shell-escape flag in LaTex system preferences

Tags: errors, minted, catchfile

I am trying to use the minted package to copy and paste python code into a LaTex document. I am using MacOS13 and using TEXShop version 4.44.

I used the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{python}

\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

After trying to compile the first time I received the following message:

```
Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTex with the -shell-escape flag.
```

After going into system preferences and putting in "--shell-escape" in the LaTex input field and compiling again, I got the following message:

```
Package catchfile Error: `"Lab 8 Report".w18' not found 
See the catchfile package documentation for explanation.
```

I have no idea what to do. I am not very good at this whole thing and would really appreciate some guidance on how to use the minted package to show my python code in my document.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't use spaces in file names.

Comment: Is there any other way though. I've been looking back at past posts about the spacing issues and I thought these were resolved now.

Comment: Many of them are, but the advice not to use spaces still holds. Sorry, I can't test on Windows.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for the help! I'm having another issue now, with regard to installing the 'pygments' package. How would I install these on my system? I don't really know where or how to download the package so that LaTex can finally work here. I'm using PyCharm, but I assume that really doesn't matter...

Comment: The issue with the space in file name is [ifplatform: filename escaping issue? · Issue #12 · wspr/will2e](https://github.com/wspr/will2e/issues/12) .