# Minted in Beamer

Tags: beamer, minted

I found the Keynote-style Portfolio beamer template [here](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucbpeal/latexposter.html) with [its package](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucbpeal/keynote-portfolio.sty). When I listed the minted package, it didn't work.

[image]

I'm using [Garuda Linux](https://garudalinux.org/). What happened?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514830/catchfile-error-when-using-shell-escape-flag-in-latex-system-preferences It is suggested that maybe you want to rename your file to remove the spaces from the file name.

Comment: OMG, thank you @WillieWong. It's solved.